# Programatically get Svelte component instance

Tags: javascript, svelte

Is it possible to get a component's instance outside components files?

For example, if I programmatically create a component using `const myComponent = new Component(options)`, I can access its instance and call methods such as `myComponent.$set(props)`.

Is it possible to get an instance of some deeply nested component, outside any component scope?

Either to get it by id (the dom class svelte-someid), or to get it internally inside a component (and use it to create a global registry of component instance references).

Comment: It seems like bind:this on another Svelte component, e.g. `<Component bind:this={instance} />` will bind its instance, but bind:this on the component container itself, e.g. `<div class="my-component" bind:this={instance}></div>` will bind the dom node instead - which makes sense - but how to get component's own instanced within the component.

Comment: Looking at the compiled code, it doesn't seem like there is a way to get this from the outside. Also the css ids are just for css, so they are not unique and instances of the same component will have the same classes. 
Anyway, I think I will not need this, and there is probably a good reason it was not implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question gains on popularity and has no answers, I will try to answer it. I'm not aware of a better method to do it.

Basically in the upper scope define an object that will serve as the component registry and expose it in the context. Then you can add the instances to the registry from the parent component containing the instance.

App.svelte

```html
<script>
    import { setContext, onMount } from 'svelte';
    
    import Parent from './Parent.svelte';
    
    const components = { };
    
    setContext('components', components);
    
    onMount(() => {
        components.child1.message = 'Child 1';
        components.child2.message = 'Child 2';
    })
</script>

<Parent></Parent>
```

Parent.svelte

```html
<script>
    import { onMount, getContext } from 'svelte';
    import Child from './Child.svelte';
    
    let child1, child2;
    
    const components = getContext('components');
    
    onMount(() => {
        components.child1 = child1;
        components.child2 = child2;
    })
</script>

<Child bind:this={child1}></Child>
<Child bind:this={child2}></Child>
```

Child.svelte

```
<svelte:options accessors/>

<script>
    export let message = '';
</script>

<p>Child: {message}</p>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f9dde6a6bbd5475d80b51d2f557edc2e?version=3.44.1)